# Thunderbird Email Message Filtering

Tags: thunderbird

I have Thunderbird 17.0.7 with 5 email accounts operating within it.  Does anyone know how I can set filters (such as sending incoming emails into particular folders) across ALL of my email addresses at once?  It seems I can only do 1 at a time.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Mozilla's Wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Filters) you can't (unless you want to manage messages in the "Local Folders"):

> Thunderbird maintains its filters on a per-account basis

and

> ...TB's filters are organized/stored per account, with an exception
>   for the "Local Folders" set of filters

Comment: actually i do want to manage them in the local folders, but apparently some filters don't work with "local folders"